# Format or pad a number column in DataGridView control (DefaultCellStyle.Format)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DatagridView control on my form.

The first column is a Record ID which can be between 3 and 5 digits on the db, but should be formatted on the front end as 5 digits with padded zeros/leading zeros.

So it looks like **901** and I want it to look like **00901**

I looked at

- [MSDN Library: How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx)

and

- [MSDN Library: How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx)

and I tried:

```
dgvDeletedRecords.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "00000"
```

in my form load event after the data is loaded into the grid

But it doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this number format "#####00000"
Code for testing I had used:

```
Me.RichTextBox.Text &= String.Format("{0:#####00000}",123)
Me.RichTextBox.Text &= Environment.NewLine
Me.RichTextBox.Text &= String.Format("{0:#####00000}",12345)
```

Tested in RichTextBox, but sure a same format will working for `DefaultCellStyle.Format`

```
 dgvDeletedRecord.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#####00000"
```

In format sting "#"-sign tell how mush number will be show(prefix zeros not shown)
Then "0"-sign tell how mush zeros will be shown, and here prefix zeros will be showed

[MSDN Number Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: what even should I put this in please

Answer (score 1):

try the following;

```
dgvDeletedRecord.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "{0:N4}"
```

Comment: is it worth trying to use the CellFormatting event like this:    _e.Value = e.Value.ToString("0", 5)_ ?